# How do I call an internal Midnight Commander command from menu entries or key bindings?

Tags: configuration, customization, mc

I try to automate some things for my [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander) setup and want to call an internal Midnight Commander command from menu entries or key bindings.

For example, I have a large number of ssh sites defined in .ssh/config,

```
# ssh (secure shell) configuration file
Host test1
    HostName 123.456.789.0
    Port 980
    User MyUserName

Host test2
    HostName test.mynet.local
    User test
    CheckHostIP no
    ..
```

1. I want to filter and sort the aliases from .ssh/config (for example with):

   ```
   grep '^Host ' .ssh/config | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | sort
   ```
2. Store the resulting list in a Midnight Commander internal list box or selection panel.
3. Select one of the entries and call the remote shell for the right file panel (like mc sh://%s...).

At least I want to store the procedure to a key binding or a Midnight Commander menu entry.

Could this be done with Midnight Commander board tools or configuration files?

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying is impossible as `mc` is not a scriptable file manager. It doesn't even have keyboard macros.

But I can think of a few weaker alternatives.

1. Use <kbd>F2</kbd>-called menu (see [the manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/mc) for format, section "Menu File Edit"). In the menu run your `grep` command, pass the list of hosts to a program like [`dialog`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/dialog) to select a host and run `mc sh://$host`. The problems with the approach: you need to learn `dialog`; there will be a second copy of `mc` which detects presence of the first and asks if you really wants to run the second. Ouch!
2. Alternatively write a script that will run the `grep` command, get the lists of hosts and programmatically edit `~/.cache/mc/history`. The file is ini-like file. You need to edit section `[inp:fishlink_cmd: Shell link to machine ]`. The keys are just consecutive numbers, the values are host names. Example:

---

```
[inp:fishlink_cmd: Shell link to machine ]
0=Host1
1=Host2
```

Now press <kbd>F9</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd>[ight], <kbd>h</kbd> (for S**h**ell command) — in the opened dialog there will be the list of hosts. Press <kbd>Alt-p</kbd>/<kbd>Alt-n</kbd> for previous/next host or open the list with mouse.